# Is there a type class for singleton Apply[A]

Tags: singleton, typeclass, scalaz, shapeless

What is a typeclass for something like this:

```
trait SingletonApply[A <: AnyRef] {
    def apply(x: A): x.type
}
```

Is there something like this already in Cats or Scalaz?

Comment: You might not want to use the term `Apply` here as it currently is used in scalaz and cats to describe something else. How exactly would one go about using an instance of this in a general way? For some `A` and an instance of this thing for `A` what can one do?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but take a look at Shapeless's `Witness`. For example, `Witness("a")` compiles, as does `val x = List(1); Witness(x)`, but not `Witness(List(1))`.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Thanks for pointing me to `Witness`. Kind of unrelated - but what does the empty `{}` do on line 30 in the `Witness`? https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/e007f47e02607fd008ceb8d22d95695aaece3f52/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L30

Comment: @pathikrit It's just an empty refinement, and somehow it keeps the type from being widened. I don't remember the full story there.

Comment: @TravisBrown: WAT. I started a separate question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903100/what-does-t-do-in-scala :)